# Turning Off VW's Hill Hold Assist

Tags: vw, jetta

I have a 2019 Jetta S (US version), and find VW's Hill Hold Assist just awful. I'm an experienced manual-gearbox user, and would much prefer that the brakes release when I take my foot off the brake pedal, and not ~3 seconds later. The dealer says it's a "safety feature" and won't disable it.

Some web pages describe turning off Hill Hold by using VAG-COM software by Ross-Tech. The car described [on this page](https://www.myturbodiesel.com/wiki/hill-hold-activation-and-disable-with-vcds-mk6-vw/) is a Golf Mk.6, a bit older and not the same as mine, but carrying a very similar electrical system and feature set. Here's [a similar thread](https://forums.ross-tech.com/showthread.php?15558-2018-B9-Audi-A5-Disable-Hill-Hold&highlight=hill%20hold) where another owner struggles with Hill Hold on a 2018 Audi A5. On both the Golf and the Audi, the Hill Hold function is in the same place, within the CPU's ABS block. Having driven and worked on VWs for decades I observe that many of the cars' systems stay the same for many years. Thus, I think it's likely that the Hill Hold function on my car will also be found in the same place, within the ABS block, as on these two VW products.

Have any of you disabled this system? If I go in and just look, am I apt to erase everything and brick the CPU?

Comment: Try another dealer first before you attempt anything especially as it is still under warranty... And the software links internally you would not believe...

Comment: @SolarMike I suspect dealers are a dead end. After I took delivery seven months ago, I wanted to disable the loud automatic door-locking that occurred at about 10 mph. The dealer said it was a "safety feature" and they couldn't change it. I easily found an inexpensive iPhone app that allowed me to turn off this (and a few other) disagreeable behaviors. Unfortunately, the app (and others like it) don't or can't address Hill Hold.

Comment: The auto door-locking is an option in the car setup menu accessed through the infotainment, at least in my 2018 GTI S. I don't remember seeing an option to disable hill-start assist. I agree that it's annoying, but I've learned to live with it.

Comment: @Spivonious On my Jetta, the infotainment screen only allows control over which doors unlock (all or driver's). The auto-lock function does not appear, and cannot be addressed unless one goes in through one of the aftermarket apps (I used, Carista).

Answer (score 3):

I have a 2019 Jetta 1.4T S and the Hill Holder was very slow to release (the manual says it is a delay of 2 seconds). I've owned two previous Jettas (2014 and 2016) and the hill holder just worked. On my first Jetta I didn't even know I had a hill holder on it until I read the manual a few months after purchasing the car.

When I talked to the dealer about the hill holder issue on my current Jetta, the response was we can't do anything.

I did purchase the Carista app and OBD adapter and I was able to change the delay from 2 seconds to 1 second. The first time I saved the new delay and went back to check it the value was still 2. I ran it a second time and it did update the value to 1 second. It has been about 2 weeks and it is working much better. Between the OBD adapter and a 1 week Carista 1 week pass I think I've spend $35.00 for the whole package. Not a bad deal.

Answer (score 1):

I also have a 2019 Jetta S, and got the same "safety" argument from my dealer.  It seems to me getting broadsided after stalling half way across an intersection would be much worse than drifting back into the stationary vehicle behind me.

The Carista app (see Google Play) allows three settings for the Hill Assist, but you can't disable it completely.  The "Normal" setting is the factory default that holds the brakes for about 2 seconds.  The "Early" setting reduces that to about 1 second.  That's better, but still annoying.  It only takes about two tenths of a second to move my right foot from the brake to the gas pedal (the reverse of the time from gas to brake measured in driver's ed.)  If anyone needs the "Late" setting, they should be required to sit in the passenger seat.

Answer (score 0):

ABS Control Module, Byte 25. Change the first *2* (right most bits to 0's) of byte 25. Leave the other bits as is. Hill hold assist will be disabled. I have tested it on 2019 Jetta S 6MT, and works. If you don't understand what I'm talking about - you probably shouldn't attempt this.